# How to generate inner class in javapoet in java

Tags: javapoet

Is there a any way to generate inner classes in javapoet library. I can generate classes with constructors and methods. But i can't figure out how to create inner classes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `TypeSpec.Builder#addType` method. See [nestedClasses()](https://github.com/square/javapoet/blob/master/src/test/java/com/squareup/javapoet/TypeSpecTest.java#L635) test in `TypeSpecTest.java`